# Add column to table programmatically

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I have some trouble to add columns to a table programmatically, maybe I look/search for the wrong keywords, but can't find a proper solution.

I got this code:

```
 ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);

         TableLayout ll=new TableLayout(this);
         HorizontalScrollView hsv = new HorizontalScrollView(this);
         TableRow tbrow=new TableRow(this);
         for(int i=0;i<mConnector.idArray.size();i++) {
             tbrow=new TableRow(this);         

                 TextView tv1=new TextView(this);
                 //String s1 = Integer.toString(i);
                 try {
                String insecticide = mConnector.insecticideArray.get(i);
                String wegedoornuis = mConnector.wegedoornluisArray.get(i);
                String dosering = mConnector.doseringArray.get(i);
                String prijs = mConnector.prijsArray.get(i);
                String bestuivers = mConnector.bestuiversArray.get(i);
                String roofvijanden = mConnector.roofvijandenArray.get(i);                    

               // String result = insecticide +" | "+wegedoornuis+" | "+dosering+" | "+prijs+" | "+bestuivers+" | "+roofvijanden;
               // int id = Integer.parseInt(s3);
                 tv1.setId(i);

                 tv1.setText(id);
                 tbrow.addView(tv1);
                 }catch(java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException e){

                 }

             ll.addView(tbrow);
         }
         hsv.addView(ll);
         sv.addView(hsv);
         setContentView(sv);
```

What I wanted is that every String (after `try{`) is getting his own column.
So like `String result` (what is now in comment signs). but then that I can adjust the columns width.

Hope you guys know what I mean, else I can always add an image to illustrate.
**Edit**
Made an image fast:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't add Strings directly to the view, but you could use text views to do the same thing. I'll show you an example that I did once, and let you figure out how to do it for your own use.

```
        TableRow row=new TableRow(this.getApplicationContext());
        TableLayout tlayout=new TableLayout(this.getApplicationContext());

        tlayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        tlayout.setBackgroundResource(R.color.background);

        row=new TableRow(this);

        TextView text1=new TextView(this.getApplicationContext());
        TextView text2=new TextView(this.getApplicationContext());
        TextView text3=new TextView(this.getApplicationContext());

        text1.setText(R.string.name);
        row.addView(text1);
        text2.setText(R.string.level);
        row.addView(text2);
        text3.setText(R.string.score);
        row.addView(text3);
        tlayout.addView(row);
        for (i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            row=new TableRow(this.getApplicationContext());
            text1=new TextView(this.getApplicationContext());
            text2=new TextView(this.getApplicationContext());
            text3=new TextView(this.getApplicationContext());


            text1.setText(high_score_name.get(i));
            row.addView(text1);
            text2.setText(""+high_score_level.get(i));
            row.addView(text2);
            text3.setText(""+high_score_score.get(i));
            row.addView(text3);
            tlayout.addView(row);
        }
```

Essentially, `high_scores_....get(i)` returns a string. Something very similar should work for your purposes.

The output will look something like this, continued down 10 rows.

```
name1  score1  level1
name2  score2  level2
```

Comment: If I see this then, `row.addView` is a column?

Comment: Basically, this will display 3 columns of data, one from each `TextView`.

Comment: Ah ok, but then 1 last thing. Isn't it a little stupid that "Google" say a column is also a row? (that is how I read it). I mean a column and a row are 2 different things.

Comment: Essentially, the row.addView is adding a  new view to that row. Since there is only one row, it adds a new column to the row. Then you finish the row, and add it to the table.